# C - Do I need to close files after opening them with system calls

Tags: c, unix, system-calls

If I open a text file with `open("file.txt",O_RDONLY)`, do I need to close it with `close()`?

Silly question, I know, but I am not entirely sure if the end of a process leaves open files open.

Comment: Just good manners to tidy up after yourself

Comment: Side note - In application code written in C, you should typically use [`fopen`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html) instead of calling `open`.  `fopen` is standard `C`, making it very portable--even to Windows, while `open` is POSIX, making it a little less portable.  So `open` gives you more "exotic" capabilities such as `mmap`, `pread` and `readv`, but at the expense of giving up portability. If you're code is only calling `open`, `read`, `write`, `lseek`, and `close`, it  *should* be calling `fopen`, `fread`, `fwrite`, `fseek`, and `fclose`.

Comment: I know, but to quote a japanese comic I like, Hi, this is Student! Or in human words, that was a limitation of the assignment - to use system calls instead of library functions to handle i/o from files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The file will remain open until you close it or your process terminates. The process terminating will invalidate the file descriptors for that process, and so in essence "close" the files.

I would always close them explicitly, and as early as reasonable.